# How to search for the records between specific CREATE_DATE range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have time stamp in the CREATE_DATE column of my table in the below format.

```
9/8/2016 5:37:35 AM
```

I need to search the records between specific CREATE_DATE range. Please help me on how to do the same.

I have used the below query but getting 
ORA-01843: not a valid month

```
select * 
from gdf.msg_pyld 
where dbms_lob.instr(pyld_clob,'4861615654')>=1 
and CREATE_DATE BETWEEN '09/08/2016 5:59:17 AM' AND '09/08/2016 5:59:17 PM';
```

Comment: What is the DATA TYPE of the column CREATE_DATE? Is it a proper Oracle "date" or is it a string (VARCHAR2)?

Comment: The DATA_TYPE for the column CREATE_DATE is 'DATE'

Comment: Does 9/8/2016 mean "September 8 2016" or "August 9 2016"?  That is, are your strings in the format MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: @JustinCave, Its in the format of MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried is a comparison of a date (a numeric type with a very special meaning) against STRINGS. This will never work.

If CREATE_DATE is indeed a DATE in Oracle, then this should work:

```
... AND CREATE_DATE BETWEEN to_date('09/08/2016 5:59:17 AM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') 
                        AND to_date('09/08/2016 5:59:17 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss PM')
```

assuming 09/08 means September 8; if instead it is supposed to mean 9 August, then change mm/dd to dd/mm in the format models. Good luck!